# Combine Matlab cell elements to a single vector

Tags: matlab, image-processing, cell-array

I have 3 480 row x 640 column images. Each pixel holds an intensity value.

I read them in matlab with this:

```
   object_intensities = cell(1,6);
   for pat=1:3
       file1 = sprintf('image%d.pgm',pat-1);
       dummy = double(imread(file1));
       object_intensities{pat} = dummy;
   end
```

Now for pat = 1 to 3, object_intensities is a cell array such that each cell element of object_intensities{pat} holds each image in a 480x640 matrix array.

Now what I need is a single structure that is 480 row x 640 column such that each cell element contains the 3 intensities of each image pixel in a single vector like this:

```
structure{row 1, column 1} = [image1_intensity @ row1 column1 image2_intensity @ row1 column1 image3_intensity @ row1 column1]
structure{row 1, column2} = [image1_intensity @ row1 column2 image2_intensity @ row1 column2 image3_intensity @ row1 column2]
.
.
structure{row 480, column 640} = [image1_intensity @ row480 column640 image2_intensity @ row480 column640 image3_intensity @ row480 column640]
```

Any way to do this without using loops but through vectorization?

Comment: Are the three images intensities for RGB channels? or does each cell of `object_intensities` actually hold a *480*-by-*640*-by-*3* matrix? If it does actually hold a single channel image (which I doubt given your use of `imread`, you might need to convert it to grey scale first) then try `cat(3,object_intensities{:})` and you'll get a nice *480*-by-*640*-by-*3* matrix. But then I guess you could have just done that when you are reading the images in,,, basically, why would you want the data structure you say you want? It's going to be really hard to work with compared to a regular matrix.

Comment: The images are already grayscale.

I would like it in this data structure I described as I need the intensity sequence of each image pixel.

Comment: A 3D matrix will still be better, cell arrays are much harder to work with. Also, I'm pretty sure `imread` will make your image RGB by default irrespective of if it's greyscale or not. You will still need to do the conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data structure you want is asking for trouble. Rather use a 3D matrix where the third dimension maps your intensities (in order). It will be much easier to work with down the line.

I suggest you create it like this:

```
object_intensities = zeros(480,640,3);
for pat=1:3
    file1 = sprintf('image%d.pgm',pat-1);
    object_intensities(:,:,pat) = rgb2gray(imread(file1));
end
```

Now what would have been `object_intensities{i,j}` on your structure is just `object_intensities(i,j,:)` and if you really need to you can call `squeeze` or `permute` or `(:)'` to make it a row vector. But just think how much easier it is now to do something like finding the average intensity per pixel

```
mean(object_intensities,3)
```

compared with the cell array

```
cellfun(@mean,object_intensities,'uni',0)  %// Just a loop in disguise
```

And what if you wanted the average per row

```
mean(object_intensities,2)
```

Try do this for the cell array and you'll see why you want to avoid it.

But if you really really want your structure, then use my code as above and call `mat2cell` on the 3D matrix:

```
mat2cell(object_intensities, ones(size(object_intensities,1),1), ones(1,size(object_intensities,2)),3)
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer but I won't be finding any mean or any other operation. 

In the legacy code I am dealing with, the data structure desired in my original post would be best for it.

Comment: @user1431515 I still doubt that. But just use my code above combined with [`mat2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) to get to your desired structure. Obviously the `mean` was just illustrative, it would apply to almost anything you want to do with these data.

Comment: Let's say I use row 250 of the 480x640x3 matrix. Is a 3x640 matrix representing row 250 of my image sequence possible?

Comment: If you use a simple 3D matrix then yes `permute(object_intensities(250,:,:),[3,2,1])` where `permute` is being used to swap the 1st and 3rd dimensions. If you use your structure then it would be something like `permute(cat(2,object_intensities{250,:}),[3,2,1])` I think

Comment: Discovered the matlab function squeeze from your post. Thank you @Dan!